# CMake cannot find directory in when used with CLion, but works with Cmake GUI

Tags: cmake, clion

I am trying to load a cmake project via the CLion IDE (which is a cracking piece of work by the way) but for some reason I cannot locate a certain directory, even though they're all located in `/usr/local/`.

The following error is returned

> Error:The following variables are used in this project, but they are
>   set to NOTFOUND. Please set them or make sure they are set and tested
>   correctly in the CMake files: Simbody_INCLUDE_DIR    used as include
>   directory in directory
>   /path/to/source

For reference I am trying to compile a simple example in the simbody physics library: https://github.com/simbody/simbody

Now for whatever reason, this must be an issue with CMake in CLion since I can generate the makefiles (using Unix Makefiles albeit on OS X) using the CMake standalone GUI.

The default cmake files from simbody can be found here: https://github.com/simbody/simbody/blob/master/cmake/SampleCMakeLists.txt

But in essence my `CMakeLists.txt` looks as such

```
# CMakeLists.txt for making a Simbody-using executable.
# This shows how to use the provided SimbodyConfig.cmake to locate a Simbody
# installation on your machine so you can use it from your own code.

cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 2.8)
project(projectx)

# Main source (and) header files
set(my_source_files projectx.cpp)

# This depends on SimbodyConfig.cmake being located somewhere predictable
# on your machine. If you have installed it somewhere that CMake won't be
# able to guess, you'll need to tell find_package where to look.
find_package(Simbody REQUIRED)

include_directories(${Simbody_INCLUDE_DIR})
link_directories(${Simbody_LIB_DIR})

add_executable(projectx ${my_source_files})
target_link_libraries(projectx ${Simbody_LIBRARIES})
```

Any suggestions would be greatly welcomed. You'll note that the comment about placing `SimbodyConfig.cmake` predictable has been heeded, since it can be found in `/usr/local/` and again it works with the CMake GUI outside of CLion (version 3.3.0, CLion ships with Version 3.2.0).

Comment: Can you get the output from CLion's Cmake configure run? Or have a look into CmakeFiles/CMakeError.log to get some insights.